# Aws lex fulfillment with aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a problem to Play audio message from aws lex code hook .is there any option can return audio file instead of text response on content .guys any ideas please share me.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Lex uses Polly to deliver audio responses.

You'll find the output voice setting under the general settings tab of your Lex bot in the Amazon Lex Console.

Programatically you need to invoke the `PostContent` method instead of `PostText`. The `PostContent` method accepts an audio stream and in turn returns an audio stream.

This page from the Developer Guide describes the main points to consider when sending and receiving voice streams to and from the Lex runtime API.

[Amazon Lex Developer Guide | PostContent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostContent.html)